# Why Laravel does not save relationships immediately?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Lets take a look at this example code:

```
$activity = new Activity(...);
$company->activities()->save($activity);

dd($company->activities);
```

This code is in controller method.

If I run this code once I'll get `[]` as an output. If I run it one more time I'll get previously saved activity. If I run it one more time, I'll get 2 (instead of 3) activities etc.

So seems like laravel doesn't save relationship right when save method is called. I've also tried so use something like `$company->push()` but without success.

Comment: Please can you take a look at your activities table to verify if data was saved successfully when you got this ` []`

Comment: I've checked of course that data is saved..

Comment: Can you supply more context? model definitions, whats fillable, protected etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when you have loaded the `activities` relationship before (either with eager loading or just by accessing it) and it is cached in the model.

You can fetch the updated collection by calling `load()` beforehand:

```
$company->activities()->save($activity);
$company->load('activities');
dd($company->activities);
```

Comment: You're just awesome :) Thanks, I indeed used model binding and eager load everything, then in the controller method I got $company with eager loaded activities. Actually I think it should be described somewhere in the docs..